Difference between Past Simple and Past Perfect with "when"

She had a ball when I came in

She had had a ball when I came in


Is the meaning the same or 2 implies that she had the ball all the time and once I entered she stopped having it?

What is your sentence intended to mean? Specifically, do you mean she was literally in possession of a ball / orb / sphere at some point in time? Or metaphorically, that she really enjoyed herself? The literal statement is a really strange thing to say. Perhaps you mean she was holding a ball, not "owning" it.

Literally ...... let it be "owning" but is there a difference in meaning between 1 and 2?

How about a different example that makes more sense? Would She smoked a cigarette when I came in and She had smoked a cigarette when I came in reflect the same thing you're asking about? Using had for Past Perfect and as an "active" verb meaning "possessed / owned" makes your example a bit weird.

She had smoked means she finished before I came in. I get that but I really want to refer to my original examples. Does 2 had had a ball mean she didin't own it when I entered?

I can't answer your question. Your example sentence is weird, and no native speaker would ever say it, so there's not much point in asking what it means. What possible connection could there be between her owning a ball (and perhaps ceasing to own it at some later point in time) and the time of my visit?

I just want to know if 2 means A she had it before I came B I didn't have it anymore when I came

It's a stupid example. Note that I could say She had had a face-lift when I saw her last week. She'd still have [had] the face-lift at the time of my visit, even though it was actually done earlier. It's not likely I''d say She had a face-lift when I saw her last week, but that would be at least possible - if I was in fact the plastic surgeon who gave her the face-lift when I saw her.

Ok. Sorry. Let me give different examples. 1 Yesterday, I saw she had a kid 2 Yesterday, I saw she had had a kid. Is the meaning the same and 2 might just emphasize that she had had a kid in the park before I was even able to see her?

Again, your example is weird. To have a kid normally means to give birth to a child. It would be unusual for it to mean she "owned" a child, but it could mean she had a child with her (either when I visited, or at some point in time before I visited. Why doesn't my [had] smoked a cigarette alternative answer your question? Why do you insist on presenting "weird" examples?

Talk about real life situations, things that people might actually say.  1. Lisa had cooked dinner when Lee arrived 2. Lisa cooked dinner when Lee arrived. Both grammatical but whose meanings are different.

1 when I  visited he had a car 2 when I visited he had a car. 1 he had it during my visit.  What about 2? Does it show that he certainly had a car before my visit and  might have or might not have it during my visit?

when doesn't control verb tense. The past perfect always means something has occurred before it, either expressly or in an implied manner. So providing examples with the past perfect without context, express or implied, makes no sense at all. Read Mari-Lou A's comment.

@Lambie I don't get what you mean. Here's my context I decided to visit my good friend and later I tell for example my mother about that meeting and now 1 When I came to visit him he had a fantastic car 2 When I came to visit him he had had a fantastic car. Now, what it the meaning of 2. Do I show that he possesed that car before my arrival and  during it and 1 just says that he had it during my visit and says nothing about before?

Here's an easier example: When I arrived, they had already eaten dinner.  When I went to visit him, he had bought a new car.  Your 2 is very awkward. Let's make it make sense: He had had a fantastic car when we were at university. When I visited him, he had a car. No had had there. Do you now see that the past prefect is preceded by simple past in these examples?

Yes, (2) would mean that he no longer owned that car but it is not at all a natural sentence. "When I asked him to show me his car, he said that he had had a fantastic one until the day before, but unfortunately he had had to sell it."
